# Powershell and registry key changing challenge

Tags: powershell, regedit

I make changes under hklm with a line like this:

```
 Set-Location HKLM:\software\afilefolder\afilefolder
```

and it works.  I also need to make a change to a current user key, I am told to do this by making a change to hkey_users, but i have about 5 machines that would run this script and based on what machine it is, i need to make a change to my location, because hkey_users has an sid as the next file folder and it changes for each user.  so based on the user, i grab the sid, I have all of them. and i set my location like this:

```
$test = "hkey_users\" + $hkeypath + "\filefolder\filefolder"
Set-Location $test
```

I cannot put the concatenation in the Set-Location line, powershell no likey, but when I do it this way, it says the following path cannot be found: C:\windows\system32\HKEY_USERS\correctsid\filefolder\filefolder

why does it look in the system32 folder?  how do i make changes to hkey_user.  please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the location just fine, with the string concatenation, just put the whole thing in the double quotes. You'll want to reference that it's in the registry just to be safe, try this out:

```
Set-Location "registry::hkey_users\$hkeypath\filefolder\filefolder"
```

That worked for me (well, I set my SID to `$mysid` and then did a `Set-Location "registry::hk_users\$mysid\software"` and that got me to my software key in the registry, under my SID).